# Python double taking up 9 bytes instead of 8 when saving

Tags: python, file, save, double

I'm having a problem when saving double precision numbers to a file. Instead of taking up 8 bytes, sometimes they end up taking 9 bytes. This is a problem because the program that reads the output file expects 8 bytes for each value.
A minimal working example of my code goes like this:

```
file = open(filename, 'w')
matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(2),dtype=numpy.dtype('d'))
matrix[0] = 0.17
matrix[1] = 0.23
matrix.tofile(file)
file.close()
```

Now i'm expecting to have a file with a size of 16 bytes. Somehow the file ends up with 17 bytes!:

```
C3 F5 28 5C 8F C2 C5 3F 71 3D 0D 0A D7 A3 70 CD 3F
```

So if we break it down:

```
C3 F5 28 5C 8F C2 C5 3F = 0.17
71
3D 0D 0A D7 A3 70 CD 3F = 0,22999999999966
```

My question is: Is it possible that the reason 0.23 takes 9 bytes is because it has no exact representation? If so, how can this problem be fixed?

Note: I'm executing this as a pluguin inside [mcEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) (a map editor for minecraft) so some fancy libraries might not be available.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode: `file = open(filename, 'wb')`

Comment: The byte `0x0A` in the floating point number was expanded to two bytes, `0x0D 0x0A`, because you opened the file in text mode.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333284/error-in-using-struct-pack-for-writing-data-to-file/33333334#33333334

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm now! Btw, i'm new here, can i somehow give you points for the answer and mark it as solved?

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate; the setup isn't quite the same, but the fundamental problem and the solution are, in fact, duplicates.  (I'm sure there are a lot more of these out there.)